# A function satisfy $x\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=0$ in a convex domain implies it is a constant

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Assume  $D \subset \mathbf{R}^2$ is a convex domain which contain original point. $f \in C^{(1)}(D)$,if $$x\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=0, \left((x,y)\in D\right)$$
show that $f(x,y)\equiv \text{constant}$

Comment: it seems it follows from [lagrange equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $(x,y)\in D$, it suffice to show that $f(x,y)=f(0,0)$. Define
$$g:[0,1]\to \Bbb R,\quad g(t)=f(tx,ty).$$
Then for every $t\in (0,1)$,
$$t\cdot g'(t)=tx\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(tx,ty)+ty\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(tx,ty)=0\Longrightarrow g'(t)=0,$$
so  $g$ is constant on $[0,1]$. The conclusion follows.